# What is the best way to access to "this" inside a sub object in javascript class?

Tags: javascript, oop

This doesn't work because f.bar.bar() in undefined.

```
var myFunction = function(foo){
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = {        
        bar: function(){                
            return this.foo;
        }
   }    
}
var f = new myFunction('foo');
alert(f.bar.bar());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always declare a variable in the parent scope:

```
var myFunction = function(foo){
    var func = this;
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = {        
        bar: function(){                
            return func.foo;
        }
   }    
}
var f = new myFunction('foo');
alert(f.bar.bar());
```

Comment: Awesome! I was just going to type this. It seems people often use "self" to refer to "this". Like var self = this.

Comment: Yeah I usually use self as well, but since this nesting could go on for ages I would suggest using a more descriptive name (aka func for myFunction - better would be myfunc). Otherwise, I have been using self for a while now :)

Comment: ^ Yeah, that makes sense! Nice suggestion :) It's definitely great to be more descriptive in that case.